# coplanar triangle intersection Olivier Devillers, Philippe Guigue

Tags: collision-detection

I think there are some tests missing in https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072100/document

This document describes the intersection of 2 triangels in 3D-space. There are 2 tests: one for crossing triangels, and one for coplanar triangles.

Figure 9 shows all necessary tests for coplanar triangels, if p1 is in region R11:

Test I: 
[r2, p2, q1], check q1 in R11?

If not: Test IIa: 
[r2, p1, q1], check q1 in R12?

If not: Test IIIa: 
[p1, p2, q1], check q1 in R13?

If yes: intersection r2p2 with p1q1.
But in this case there are no further checks.
r1 is not checked!
r1 could be in R11, R12 or R13.
If r1 is in Region R13, you have to intersect r2p2 with p1r1.
And eventually you have to make some intersections of q1r1 with p2q2 or q2r2.

Have Devillers and Guigue forgotten these tests??

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the answer. This algorithm just checks, whether 2 triangles intersect. The result is not a new polygon, triangle or vertex, the result is just a true or a false. As soon as the algorithm has detected an intersection it stops looking for further intersections. That´s why r1 isn´t checked any more in this special case.

Answer (score 0):

This program is really confusing.

If triangles are coplanar, then it is checked in 2D-space, whether the triangles are intersecting.

If they are not coplanar, then it is not only checked in 3D-space, but also the intersection-points are calculated.